# Including all the ultra-wealthy, what's the average income in the US?

Tags: united-states, calculation, income, capital-gain

The ultra-wealthy typically receive fairly little of their income as wages. [Larry Page, Sergei Brin](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1288776/000119312506010016/d8k.htm), [Steve Jobs](http://files.shareholder.com/downloads/AAPL/1661508868x0x531628/b6ec469d-aff8-4eef-9077-1defc2258f6b/2012_Proxy.pdf), [Larry Ellison](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1341439/000119312514350236/d778087ddef14a.htm), and [Mark Zuckerberg](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1326801/000132680115000019/facebook2015proxystatement.htm#sC447DF77A35CAA858BEC7AE988C25A4D) all receive or received no more than $1 per year, though all have substantial income from stock ownership. Unsurprisingly, it is fairly difficult to find an actual number for average salaries including all non-salary income, but my question is this:

If you include all stock options/grants, real estate gifts, other payment in securities, all other non-salary income and finally all salaries, what is the average individual income in the United States?

Comment: I don’t think Steve Jobs has any income at all.

Comment: If you think about it, "income" means ... **what you pay the IRS!**  The sense of your question is they "hide" income, by taking a $1 "salary", and the rest comes as some sort of other profit share, stock or whatever.  The good thing from the point of view of your question is that the IRS "doesn't care" about such tricks  :)  So, the actual amount reported to the IRS is the answer you're looking for.  The details well explained in BenM's answer.

Comment: @Fattie I get what you mean, but hopefully nobody is paying *all* of their income to the IRS...

Comment: I don't think that this is a question relevant to **personal** finance & money. But it might be a good question for https://economics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think you need to specify exactly what you're asking for.  Do you mean the average over everyone, or just average over people who earn income, or report it to the IRS?  Are Social Security benefits included? And so on...

Comment: @jamesqf my apologies if this wasn't clear from the question. I'm asking about all income, reported and unreported, for all Americans, averaged as dollars and cents per American. No holds barred

Comment: @CactusCake They're not paying all their income to the IRS, but they should be reporting all their income to the IRS. That said, whether it helps to answer the question or not depends on what sort of statistics the IRS gives out.

Answer (score 5):

The IRS publishes [statistics](https://www.irs.gov/statistics) on the actual numbers claimed on tax returns.

The most recent summary report on individual tax returns is from [2015](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-soi/15inintaxreturns.pdf). In that report, it is shown that there were 149,938,000 individual returns filed for 2015. The total income claimed was $10,360,403,000,000. This number is before any of the above-the-line deductions.

Doing the division, you end up with an average total income of $69,098 on all the tax returns filed.

Married Filing Jointly returns are counted as 1, not 2, in the number above. To get the average personal income, we must note that there were 54,210,000 joint returns filed. Counting those as 2, the average personal income of taxpayers in 2015 was $50,749.

Comment: Was there something you saw that made it seem ambiguous? To me it seemed simply the total number of returns filed, wondering if I missed something.

Comment: @HartCO You are right. I have removed the ambiguity.

Comment: +1 I bet it's a close enough approximation of average household income, but thinking maybe MFS should be combined into one household (in some cases), and not sure how students who work but live with parents should get counted. Those probably contribute to some of the difference between IRS figures and Census Bureau figures.

Comment: @HartCO “Household” isn’t the best word here, so I removed it and calculated the average personal income.

Comment: Yeah gets complicated in either case, counting MFJ as two means a lot of people are attributed income who do not actually earn any.

Comment: It might be noted that the average can be significantly different from the Median.

Comment: @Norm And for something like income, the average almost always is much higher than the median. Because there's a minimum of zero, but no maximum, so you tend to get a lot of people grouped toward the low end, and then very rich people stretching the graph out to the right.

Comment: This is "per tax return" and not "per American". A problem with questions like this is that you get into definitions. Like do we average over all Americans, including 3 year old children with zero income? If you count per taxpayer, then when a teenager gets his first minimum wage job, he brings the average down, even though his family's income just went up.

Comment: @jay - Exactly. Often with things like income its more informative to look at median rather than average.

Answer (score 0):

The [US Census Bureau is tasked with collecting this data](https://www.census.gov/topics/income-poverty/income.html):

> The Census Bureau reports income from several major household surveys
>   and programs. Each differs from the others in some way, such as the
>   length and detail of its questionnaire, the number of households
>   included (sample size), and the methodology used

The linked webpage links to various data tables, and publications related to income.

Comment: link-only answers are discouraged